# Правильно ли оформлены приложения?

Tags: пунктуация

Привязка многих валют стран-республик бывшего СССР к рублю... 
или Привязка многих валют стран - республик бывшего СССР к рублю...

Расчеты предприятий-потребителей продукции российских предприятий более или менее стабильны. Или Расчеты предприятий - потребителей продукции российских предприятий более или менее стабильны.

Разные политические и экономические условия заставляют страны-спонсоры ЕС провести ряд ограничений по въезду в страну вопреки шенгенским соглашениям и начать процедуру выхода из ЕС. или Разные политические и экономические условия заставляют страны - спонсоры ЕС провести ряд ограничений по въезду в страну вопреки шенгенским соглашениям и начать процедуру выхода из ЕС.

Answer (score 2):

Во всех указанных примерах ставится тире, а не дефис.

Постановка одного тире (а не двух тире) соответствует тесной смысловой связи приложения и определяемого слова . 
В этом случае приложение имеет более конкретное значение, чем определяемое слово, которое часто бывает словом с неопределённым значением  (страна, предприятие). Но такое тире можно назвать  условно тире-дефисом, так как приложение и определяемое слово произносятся без паузы (слитное произношение, как при дефисном написании).

Другой пример: Специальное устройство –  акваланг (пауза) используется при работе подводников.

Answer (score 1):

> Привязка многих валют стран-республик
> бывшего СССР к рублю...

Нужно тире:  *стран -- республик бывшего СССР...* (многословное приложение). Плюс я бы переставил слово "многих":

*Привязка валют **многих** стран...*

> Расчеты предприятий-потребителей
> продукции российских предприятий...

Нужно тире: *предприятий -- потребителей продукции...* Плюс смущает сочетание: *расчёты стабильны* (?).

> Разные политические и экономические
> условия заставляют страны-спонсоры
> ЕС...

Здесь дефис употреблён правильно.

Comment: ПОЯСНЕНИЕ. === В третьем примере нужен именно дефис (не тире!), причём независимо от того, какое из слов -- страны или спонсоры -- считать приложением. См. § 120.1.б, § 120.1.в: http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=66#pp66
===
В первом и втором примерах -- тире. См. § 154.1: http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=80#pp80

Comment: Мне кажется, здесь должен быть единый принцип, т. е. если тире, то везде, а если дефис в третьем случае, то почему не во втором и не в первом?..

Comment: Здесь дело не в форме (что считать приложением), а в разном понимании смысла. 1) Дефис: страны-спонсоры ЕС - это страны,  которые в ЕС числятся спонсорами. 2) Тире: страны - спонсоры ЕС - это страны, которые спонсируют ЕС как единое экономическое пространство. Не исключено, что здесь возможны оба варианта и обе формы написания.